# php autoscroll issues with .js

Tags: php, javascript, html, chat

Is there any SIMPLE way to create an autoscroll within a php/html chatbox? 
I tried a few things, but they all interfered with other .js elements on the page and all end up not working.

to view live code of the chatbox click here!

heres what i have at the moment

```
// jQuery Document
 $(document).ready(function(){
//If user submits the form
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});

//Load the file containing the chat log
function loadLog(){     
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "log.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
            }               
        },
    });
}
setInterval (loadLog, 2500);    //Reload file every 2.5 seconds

//If user wants to end session
$("#exit").click(function(){
    var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
    if(exit==true){window.location = 'index.php?logout=true';}

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the weight you get your scroll height doesn't work. I have tried to type it in the command line of FF and didn't get an int nor an object.

Don't try to get the scroll height. Scroll further down... and more than that.

```
$("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');
```

I have only tried with FF, but should work across most browsers.

Then, your success function is dead simple :

```
success: function(html){        $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');

            $("#chatbox").html(html);
            $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');
}
```

$(".msgln").last().offset().top

Comment: PS : I was feedling with getting an offset like that before realizing that it was not necessary to get an offset :  $(".msgln").last().offset().top

Comment: But now it doesn't let me scroll up o.O

Comment: I've seen you have taken another path at the moment : put comments in a div for now :) good luck for your site.